span a figure over two/multiple pages
I have a large figure in terms of hight dimension which I would like to add to the Appendix of my work in LaTex. Is there a way to have such figure spanning over pages without needing to resort to \subfigures, or cropping it beforehand?
I looked at some posts on this topic but it seems there is not a clear way of doing it; I've seen also the use of \ContinuedFloat that, for some reason, didn't work for me...
Anyway, I attach the figure and if anyone has a solution I'll be very happy to test it.
P.S. for visibility I would like to have the figure set to \textwidth, also I need it to be in PDF format so it support the Scalable Vector Graphics, although I couldn't upload a PDF for the restrictions on file types
EDIT for @David Carlisle
Here, is a MWE. Somehow, in spite of how small I set the first \includegraphics, LaTex always attempts to squish everything in the same page. Am i missing something?
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=6.5in]{example-image}
\includegraphics[width=6.5in]{example-image}
\caption[\textbf{Pipeline optimizing a \texttt{PGGB} pangenome for small variant calling}]{\textbf{Pipeline optimizing a \texttt{PGGB} pangenome for small variant calling.} \dots}
\end{center}
\end{figure}


you could include it twice with \includegraphics just cropping within tex you don't need to crop it beforehand. but really if you still have the source for that it would probably look better to regenerate it with each of the the three sections directly inlined as sections of your appendix

@DavidCarlisle I see what you mean. So, basically since I'm in possession of the source I can generate 2-to-3 cropped PDF for the image and add all of them within the same \begin{figure} ... \end{figure} using 2 (or 3) \includegraphics. Let me know whether this is the case, thanks!

yes or not include them as pdf at all but simply input the tex source into your document adjusting the style to whatever fits in your document.

@DavidCarlisle I tried a few possible combinations but LaTex once I add two \includegraphics in the same \begin{figure} ... \end{figure} seems to be wanting  to squeeze them in the same page. I'm trying to break page after the first image, how can I do so? If needed, I can upload the actual images for testing.

a figure is a box and never splis over a page

@DavidCarlisle oh so I actually need two figures to do the job, each one containing one \includegraphics?

or no figure at all, since you don't want the images to float you don't need figure

You will however need \captionof{figure}{...}

@JohnKormylo not necessarily, if the pdf is text then you can just treat it visually as part of the document you don't (necessarily) need to treat it as a captioned insertion even if technically it is input using \includegraphics

You can crop the figure while keeping its scalable pdf nature eg this splits the figure into three chunks spread over two pages

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Appendix}

% 595.276 841.89

% top 1/4

\noindent\hspace*{-4cm}\fbox{\includegraphics[viewport=0 631.5 596 842,clip]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}}

\bigskip

% middle 1/4
\noindent\hspace*{-4cm}\fbox{\includegraphics[viewport=0 421 596 631.5,clip]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}}

\clearpage

% bottom half
\noindent\hspace*{-4cm}\fbox{\includegraphics[viewport=0 0  596 421,clip]{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}}

\end{document}

Although if you have the TeX source for the original poster I would not include it as PDF, just \input  the body of the tex code then you can more easily adjust to fit with the page size and formatting of the document, for example not using the three headings in the current image at all but rather using \subsection as part of your document structure.

this works; however, I'm getting a boxed, enlarged version of my two PDFs. Should I play with the parameters in viewport? Sorry, but I'm not very practical with LaTex yet and your approach it is something totally new to me. Also, I wish to preserve the images without outline boxes if possible, let me know. Thanks!

@Matteo the frame box is just for debugging, see the \fbox{....}  which you can remove. Especially if you remove the clip option the box is useful to see what part of the original  image would be clipped at the current settings.  This answer includes the example image at its natural size, but you can add any of the usual \includegraphics options, scale=0.5 or width=\textwidth or whatever you need

awesome thanks a lot. Is there a way to have a caption that shows in the LOF as well, or given we are not using a float environment this isn't possible. In fact, that's the error I'm getting once I try to add one.

yes put them in a figure or use \captionof{figure}{×××××}  from capt-of package
